# Як перекласти "recapture", бажано одним словом?

Tags: from-english, терміни

Цікавить переклад назви методу для оцінювання чисельності популяції в природі - **capture/recapture**.

> Метод припускає, що кожна тварина може потрапити в пастку
>   рівноймовірно. Припустимо, що ми зловили 10 тварин, позначили і
>   відпустили. Кілька місяців потому ми зловили 20 тварин, оглянули і
>   відпустили. 4 з 20 були з нашими позначками. З цього можна оцінити
>   розмір популяції - 50.

[r2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=recapture&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) пропонує *повторне захоплювання*, але це занадто довго і з косою рискою не клеїться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контексті цього методу

- capture/recapture - **зловити/повторити**

Що саме повторити зрозуміло з контексту. Також є рима:)

Answer (score 2):

Як на мене, підходить пара **[схопити](http://sum.in.ua/s/skhopljuvaty)**/**[перехопити](http://sum.in.ua/s/perekhopljuvaty)**

> СХОПЛЮВАТИ, юю, юєш, недок., **СХОПИТИ**, схоплю, схопиш; мн. схоплять;
>   док., перех.
>
> 1. Брати, хапати кого-, що-небудь швидким рухом рук, зубів і т. ін.
>
> //  за що. Хапаючи за що-небудь, тримати, стискати. — Я вже схоплюю
>   жар-птицю за хвіст і знов упускаю її (Олесь Донченко, VI, 1957, 621);
>
> ПЕРЕХОПЛЮВАТИ, юю, юєш, недок., **ПЕРЕХОПИТИ**, хоплю, хопиш; мн.
>   перехоплять; док.
>
> 1. перех. Зупинити кого-, що-небудь під час руху.
>
> //  Наздоганяти у дорозі з метою затримання.
>
> Князь Святослав велів
>   двом тисячам кінних воїв негайно переплисти Дунай і мчати лівим
>   берегом до Доростола, щоб перехопити болгарські лодії [човни] (Семен
>   Скляренко, Святослав, 1959, 355);

Тоді [беремо з вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture)

> Mark and recapture  is a method commonly used in ecology  ...
>   Other names for this method, or closely  related methods, include
>   capture-recapture, capture-mark-recapture, mark-recapture,
>   sight-resight, mark-release-recapture, ...

і перекладаємо

> Схопити та перехопити - це метод, який широко використовується в
>   екології ... Інші назви цього метода, чи споріднених -
>   схопити-перехопити, схопити-помітити-перехопити, помітити-перехопити,
>   sight-resight, помітити-відпустити-перехопити, ...

Comment: *перехопити* не відображає повторність дії, може *пересхопити* підійшло б, але такого слова нема і я не певен, що воно б позначало повторну дію, як-от *переробити*

Comment: Можливо доречно було б перекласти іншою частиною мови: "схоплювана тварина". Хоча слово мені і показується підкреслене червоним, але повинно означати повторюваність дії. Схоплена - разова дія у минулому, схоплювана - схоплена два або більше разів. Дієслово пересхопити (перезахопити) також повинно бути правильним. Інша річ, що можливо неточно перекладати слово "capture" словом "схопити". Зловити або спіймати можуть бути кращими відповідниками. Відповідно: перезловлена, переспіймана - обидва слова є новотворами, тож не мають за собою закріпленого значення, як у випадку із словом "перехопити".

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо чудовий коментар! Гадаю його варто оформити як відповідь, щоб за нього можна було проголосувати і підняти його на гору, бо зараз я його прочитав чисто випадково. Дякую!